# SAS Updating records sequentially

Tags: sas

I have hundreds of thousands of IDs in a large dataset.

Some records have the same ID but different data points. Some of these IDs need to be merged into a single ID. People registered for a system more than once should be just one person in the database.

I also have a separate file that tells me which IDs need to be merged, but it's not always a one-to-one relationship. For example, in many cases I have x->y and then y->z because they registered three times. I had a macro that essentially was the following set of if-then statements:

```
if ID='1111111' then do; ID='2222222'; end; 
if ID='2222222' then do; ID='3333333'; end;
```

I believe SAS runs this one record at a time. My list of merged IDs is almost 15k long, so it takes forever to run and the list just gets longer. Is there a faster method of updating these IDs?

Thanks

EDIT: Here is an example of the situation, except the macro is over 15k lines long due to all the merges.

```
data one; 
input ID $5. v1 $ v2 $;
cards;
11111 a b
11111 c d
22222 e f
33333 g h
44444 i j
55555 k l
66666 m n
66666 o p
;
run;

%macro ID_Change;
if ID='11111' then do; ID='77777'; end; *77777 is a brand new ID;
if ID='22222' then do; ID='88888'; end; *88888 is a new ID but is merged below;
if ID='88888' then do; ID='99999'; end; *99999 becomes the newer ID;
%mend;

data two; set one; %ID_Change; run;
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show an example structure of some input records and the "separate file" structure (flat file / SAS data set / etc.) with some example records and what you would want the output to look like based on the example input records.

Answer (score 2):

A hash table will greatly speed up the process. [Hash tables](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/65287/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1b4cbtmb049xtn1vh9x4waiioz4.htm) are one of the little-used, but highly effective, tools in SAS. They're a bit bizarre since the syntax is very different from standard SAS programming. For now, think of it as a way to merge data together in-memory (a big reason as to why it's so fast).

First, create a dataset that has the conversions that you need. We want to match up by `ID`, then convert it to `New_ID`. Consider `ID` as your **key** column, and `New_ID` as your **data** column.

```
dataset: translate

ID     New_ID
111111 222222
222222 333333
```

In a hash table, you need to consider two things:

1. The Key column(s)
2. The Data column(s)

The Data column is what will be replacing observations matched by the Key column. In other words, `New_ID` will be populated every time there's a match for `ID`.

Next, you'll want to do your hash merge. This is performed in the data step.

```
data want;
     set have;

     /* Only declare the hash object on the first iteration. 
        Otherwise it will do this every record. */
     if(_N_ = 1) then do;
           declare hash id_h(dataset: 'translate'); *Declare a hash object called 'id_h';
           id_h.defineKey('ID');                    *Define key for matching;
           id_h.defineData('New_ID');               *The new ID after matching;
           id_h.defineDone();                       *Done declaring this hash object;
           call missing(New_ID);                    *Prevents a warning in the log;
     end;

    /* If a customer has changed multiple times, keep iterating until 
       there is no longer a match between tables */
    do while(id_h.Find() = 0);

        _loop_count+1; *Tells us how long we've been in the loop;

       /* Just in case the while loop gets to 500 iterations, then 
          there's likely a problem and you don't want the data step to get stuck */
       if(_loop_count > 500) then do;
            put 'WARNING: ' ID ' iterated 500 times. The loop will stop. Check observation ' _N_;
            leave;
       end; 

        /* If the ID of the hash table matches the ID of the dataset, then
           we'll set ID to be New_ID from the hash object;
        ID = New_ID; 
    end;

    _loop_count = 0;

   drop _loop_count;
run;
```

This should run very quickly and provide the desired output, assuming that your lookup table is coded in the way that you need it to be.

Comment: Given the requirement for multiple re-mappings you probably want a `DO` loop instead of just an `IF` so that it will assign `ID = new_id` many times in those cases.

Comment: A while loop would be even better seeing as the number of iterations is unknown.  Using a do loop is basically crossing your fingers and hoping it's correct.  Also, a while loop is likely to reduce the total number of operations as you're not forcing it to repeat it 5 times for every obs if it only needs to be done once.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking :) Changed it to a flexible option.

Comment: `do while(id_h.Find()=0 ); ID = New_ID; end;`

Comment: This is the better solution.  I do think that may be a bit advanced for the OP, given that he/she is currently hard-coding values into a macro.  But I have learned from it too.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `PROC SQL` or a `MERGE` step against your separate file (after you have created a separate dataset from it, using `infile` or `proc import`) to append this unique id to all records.  If your separate file contains only the duplicates, you will need to create a dummy unique id for the non-duplicates.
2. Do `PROC SORT` with `BY` unique id and timestamp of signup.
3. Use a `DATA` step with the same `BY` variables.  Depending on whether you want to keep the first or last signup, do `if first.timestamp then output;` (or last, etc.)

Or you could do it all in one `PROC SQL` using a `left join` to the separate file, a `coalesce` step to return a dummy unique id if it is not contained in the separate file, a `group by` unique id, and a `having max(timestamp)` (or min).  You can also `coalesce` any other variables you might want to try to preserve across signups -- for example, if the first signup contained a phone number and successive signups were missing that data point.

Without a reproducible example it's hard to be more specific.